# Use less than or greater than in where clause with a regex in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I need to write a query that finds a number that can be less than, less than or equal, greater than, greater than or equal clause combined with a regex.
Is there a way to include the less than or greater than clause in the query, instead of rewriting the regex?

I need to get all the answers that contain a number less than or greater than a value depending on certain conditions.

So far I have this:

```
my_regex = "(^|;)([#{value}])($|;)"
Model.where("answer ~* ?", my_regex)
```

This will return the records that contain the value but not if I need greater than the value of the regex.

For example, if I need a value greater than 2:
if `answer` is `"1;3;5;6;7;10"`  I would like to avoid rewriting the regexp to "(^|;)([#{value}-9]|1[0-9])($|;)" is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your `answer` column is unfortunate but not hopeless. The `~*` operator you're currently using tells me that this is PostgreSQL so you could unpack `answer` into an SQL array:

```
regexp_split_to_array(answer, ';')::int[]
```

and then use `any` to look for your desired value:

```
...where("? < any(regexp_split_to_array(answer, ';')::int[])", 2)
```

The `::int[]` is a type cast to convert the array of strings that `regexp_split_to_array` gives you into the numbers that you want for the comparison. Then you check if **any** of the array elements are greater than two.

---

You could also change the format of the `answer` column to be an actual array of integers and say the much simpler:

```
...where('? < any(answer)', 2)
```

ActiveRecord knows how to work with PostgreSQL arrays too so `model.answer` would be a Ruby array over in Rails-land without any extra mucking about.